# Swift Append to Array after indexpath.row

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, append

I have a swift Array that I populate a `UITableview` with.

e.g

```
var array: Array<String> = ["ExampleString1","ExampleString2","ExampleString3"]
```

My question is how to do append all items that come after the `Indexpath.row` I press to a new array.

e.g I press the the first `UITableview` cell which is row 0 and in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` I can pick up the `indexpath`

```
let test = array[indexPath.row]
```

If I pressed the first cell I want to add ExampleString2 and ExampleString3 by appending to my new array

```
var newArray: Array<String> = []
newArray.append(Everything After Indexpath that was pressed.)
```

Comment: Use a for loop, starting at indexPath.row+1 up to array.count-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = ["ExampleString1", "ExampleString2", "ExampleString3"]
let indexPath = 0 // Your indexPath

let newArray = array.enumerate().filter { $0.index > indexPath }.map { $0.element }
```

Something like this.

And using Paulw11's suggestion: (if he posts his answer I'll delete mine)

```
var newArray: [String] = []

for index in indexPath + 1...array.count - 1 {
    newArray += [array[index]]
}
```

Another variation based on Paulw11's suggestion:

```
let newArray = array[indexPath + 1...array.count - 1].map { $0 }
```

Or:

```
let newArray = Array(array[indexPath + 1...array.count - 1])
```

They all print out:

```
print(newArray) // ["ExampleString2", "ExampleString3"]
```

You'll have to add some safety checks because the way it is right now will cause an error if your indexPath.row is the last element. In that case, my original answer (the first one) is more safe.

Comment: Thanks This is exactly what what I needed. Much appreciated.